# React Native - Switching to other Screen after Permission Granted

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-permissions

So I have 2 screens, the SplashScreen.js and the Auth.js. In the SplashScreen.js is were all the Permissions Android run and if it is granted it will navigate it to the AuthScreen.js.

But in my case, after it granted the app crashes. I just don't know why.

So what I want to happen is, after the Permission Android granted it will navigate it to the AuthScreen.js.

Here are my codes:

SplashScreen.js: This is inside the `class SplashScreen extendes Component {}`

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  timePassed: false
};
}

componentDidMount() {
this.permissionAndroid();
};

setTimePassed() {
this.setState({timePassed: true})
};

permissionAndroid = () => {
try {
  const granted = PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
    [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
    {
      title: "Location Permission",
      message: "You have to, because it's a party app! " + "So you can enjoy more viewing events.",
      buttonNeutral: "Ask me later",
      buttonNegative: "Cancel",
      buttonPositive: "OK"
    },
  );
  if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("All permision enabledenabled")
    // this.setTimePassed();
    this.setState({timePassed: true})
  } else {
    console.log('Location Permission Denied');
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
}

render() {
if(!this.state.timePassed) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
} else {
  return <AuthScreen/>
}
};
```

I also have the code of Permission Android outside the Class with `async function`, I didn't use this right now because `this.setState({})` or function `setTimePassed()` will not work I think because it is outside the Class.

This is another option to make app works, but I'm just not sure how the `setState({})` or the `setTimePassed()` will work when it pass outside the Class.

This code is in the SplashScreen.js also: (it is also same with the function `permissionAndroid` it just have a async function)

```
async function requestLocationPermission() {
try {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
  [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
  {
    title: "Location Permission",
    message: "You have to, because it's a party app! " + "So you can enjoy more viewing events.",
    buttonNeutral: "Ask me later",
    buttonNegative: "Cancel",
    buttonPositive: "OK"
  },
);
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  console.log("All permision enabledenabled")
  // setTimePassed();
  this.setState({
    timePassed: true
  });
} else {
  console.log('Location Permission Denied');
}
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start off by marking `permissionAndroid` as async because it is an asynchronous function and use `await`. I've checked the React Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid#requestmultiple) and they state that `PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple()` :

"Prompts the user to enable multiple permissions in the same dialog and returns an object with the permissions as keys and strings as values (see result strings above) indicating whether the user allowed or denied the request or does not want to be asked again."

So this function does not return a `boolean` like `PermissionsAndroid.request()`, but rather an `object` with the following structure :

```
const granted = PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
    [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
    {
      title: "Location Permission",
      message: "You have to, because it's a party app! " + "So you can enjoy more viewing events.",
      buttonNeutral: "Ask me later",
      buttonNegative: "Cancel",
      buttonPositive: "OK"
    }
);

console.log(granted); // { PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION : true, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE : false }
```

As for `requestLocationPermission`, you're right : you can't call `setState` outside of a `Component` class. You could use callbacks as arguments in which you would perform the required actions for the two scenarios (granted and denied). Or you could simply move the code into the class.

@dimonD is right, you should use a navigation framework such as React Navigation or React Native Navigation.

Comment: I'm using the react native navigation but there is no feature to navigate it to a simple screen. Only push screens, modal, tabs, etc. Unlike react navigation there is a function to simple navigate it to a simple screen.

Comment: So you mean if I use the `requestMultiple` only 1 permission will be granted and return to `true`? so the second permission will be return to `false`?

Comment: **react native navigation v1

Comment: Already working now! This is how I did it, I use the async function again, then use setTimeOut. setTimeOut will not start until the Permission is already granted, so when it already granted the setTimeOut will start and navigate it to the AuthScreen.js. I think this all work because of the await

Comment: Good job solving this on your own but I don't think using `setTimeout` is very wise here as the user may take longer than usual to accept/decline. What I meant earlier is that your have to check each permission separately instead to make sure they've all been granted. `request()` returns a `Promise<boolean>` which is why you can check if it is true but request multiple returns a `Promise<any>` (am object containing each permission and whether it was granted or not). Check the link in my original answer.

Comment: I try earlier not to accept or decline the Permission but nothing happens, it runs perfectly. As I read about the `async await` they block the other functions until the function in the `async await` is done. That's why maybe it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some navigation, for example reactnavigation.org.
After user permission is granted, you simple do

navigation.navigate("Screen you want to show")

Also is a some concept for auth flow, where you can implement what should happen before/after user get a LoginScreen.
You can check it here 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: How can I do that with react native navigation v1?

Comment: Already working now! This is how I did it, I use the `async function` again, then use `setTimeOut`. `setTimeOut` will not start until the Permission is already granted, so when it already granted the `setTimeOut` will start and navigate it to the AuthScreen.js. I think this all work because of the `await`